# RandomForestRegressor, feature importances

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

I use  Random Forest Regressor and have 43 features.
When I run the following code:

```
print(clf.feature_importances_)
```

I get the next result:

```
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

How much do I understand, my random forest model use only one feature to predict outcome?

Whether it's ok or not?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you tried

Comment: Looks like you have a feature which corresponds directly to the targets. Are you sure that the features dont contain anything which would only be known after the target is known, or maybe by mistake you are using the target values as a column in features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot each of your features against your label value and manually see what the model is looking at to analyze your results. Also check the accuracy of your model, if it's not very high this could also be why you're seeing a strange result.